# getting xml child nodes values

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dynamic, foreach

i have an xml look like this

```
<customlocation>
    <path>xxxxx</path>
    <filetype>xxxxx</filetype>
    <filetype>xxxxx</filetype>
    <filetype>xxxxx</filetype>
                .
                .
                .
    <filename>xxxxx</filename>
    <filename>xxxxx</filename>
    <filename>xxxxx</filename>
                .
                .
                .
    <delete>xxxxx</delete>
</customlocation>
<customlocation>
    <path>xxxxx</path>
    <filetype>xxxxx</filetype>
    <filetype>xxxxx</filetype>
    <filetype>xxxxx</filetype>
                .
                .
                .
    <filename>xxxxx</filename>
    <filename>xxxxx</filename>
    <filename>xxxxx</filename>
                .
                .
                .
    <delete>xxxxx</delete>
</customlocation>
                .
                .
```

you can have as many customlocation tags as you want -dynamic- and i can get these tags easily like this:

```
            XElement doc = XElement.Load(xmlFilePath);
            foreach(XElement elm in doc.Descendants().Elements("customlocation"))
        {
```

but the problem is how to search inside this for filetype and filename tags i searched for this for long time but no luck till now so please help
thanks alraedy

Comment: What do you want to search?  and what is input and expected output?

Comment: im searching for filetype and filename tags to get their values and store it in an array note: you can't see it cause i  just found out putting them in tags make them invisible

Comment: @HariPrasad i can't just use string sss= elm.Element("filetype").value; there has to be iteration depend on how many tags we have
thanks already for your comment

Comment: Use a where like code below : var results = doc.Descendants().Elements("customlocation").Where(x => (string)x.Element("filetype") == "jpeg").Select(y => new { path = (string)y.Element("path")}).ToArray();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Elements` finds only those elements that are direct descendents, `Descendants` finds children at any level ( i.e. children, grand-children)

Since you want to construct an array of `filetpe` and `filename`, you could do this.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
var filetypes = doc.Descendants("filetype").Select(x=>x.Value).ToArray();
var filenames = doc.Descendants("filename").Select(x=>x.Value).ToArray();
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jFUKHb)

Comment: that worked actually BUT this returns all file type values in an array i should be able to distinguish filetype values from each customlocation tag is there a way to do that?
thank you

Comment: It is possible, but which attribute do you want to use to distinguish customlocation?

Comment: i can add attributes like this
<customlocation id='1'> would that help??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<string> Values = new List<string>();    
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("Server.xml"));
foreach(XElement elm in doc.Descendants().Elements("customlocation"))
{
  foreach (XElement ele in elm.Elements("filetype"))
  {
    Values.Add(ele.Value);
  }
}
```